# Outlook 2010, command line options for exporting some settings

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, exchange, rules, batch-file

For Outlook 2010, are there command line options I can use to export safe senders and rules using a simple bat file?

(There are 2 sets of rules.  1 set for an Exchange account and 1 set used for multiple pop/imap accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the [Command-line switches for Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx) can be found here. Another [website](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm) has a short how-to and all the switches for MS Outlook.